# How to track new socket id when the browser reload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am new to socket.io. I am working on a real-time notification feature using socket.io. Everything is working fine. But when reloading the browser the socketId of the user is changed and the notification feature is not working. My question is how to track the new socketId when the browser refresh.

```
//server.js-> socket.io code
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});

let onlineUsers: any = [];

const addNewUser = (username: any, socketId: any) => {
  !onlineUsers.some((user: any) => user.username === username) &&
    onlineUsers.push({ username, socketId });
  console.log("o", onlineUsers);
};

const getUser = (username: any) => {
  return onlineUsers.find((user: any) => user.username === username);
};
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
  console.log(socket.id);

  socket.on("newUser", (username: any) => {
    console.log("username", username);
    // console.log("socketId", socket);
    addNewUser(username, socket.id);
  });
  socket.on("sendNotification", ({ senderName, receiverName, action }) => {
   
    const receiver = getUser(receiverName);
   
    io.to(receiver?.socketId).emit("getNotification", {
      senderName,
      action,
    });
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected");
  });
});
```

```
//client side socket.io code
 useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userData: any = localStorage.getItem("user");
    setUser(JSON.parse(userData)?.name);
    // console.log("userId", userId, socket.emit);
    if (user) {
      socket?.emit("newUser", user);
    }
  }, [socket, user]);
```

```
//navbar component
 React.useEffect(() => {
    socket?.on("getNotification", (data: any) => {
      console.log("data2", data);
      setNotifications((prev): any => [...prev, data]);
    });
  }, [socket]);
```

Please try to elaborate on your answer/ suggestion or reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a more simple way. Instead of using a socket.id create a room with the user's unique id(stored in DB). Now emit and receive notification on that room(user's unique id).

```
io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
   socket.on("joinrooms", async (data) => {
    socket.join(data.userId);
   });

   socket.on("sendMessage", async (data) => {
   console.log("message", data);
   io.to(data.userId).emit("sendMessage", data);
  });
});

/* Must Read section
Joinrrom data sample
data={
  userId:123 //User's unique id.
}

sendMessage data sample
data={
  userId:123, //User's unique id.
}
Here I'm creating a room from the user's unique id(stored in DB) so whenever I 
want to send to a particular user I will emit an 
event("io.to(data.userId).emit") using the user's 
a unique id that way everything will be handled using userId instead of 
socketId so now doesn't matter how many socketId is created.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is even possible in socket.io, it's supposed to get a new socket ID on refresh, but you could maybe do something with IP addresses? Maybe use one of these:

`socket.handshake.headers["x-forwarded-for"], socket.handshake.headers["x-real-ip"], or socket.handshake.address.` 
you could keep an "ipmap" array and add these values to the map on connect and track users that way, because IP addresses don't change when you refresh your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution to this problem. Probably this is not the perfect solution but work should be done. Explain the solution to others.

Actually, the problem was in this function

```
const addNewUser = (username: any, socketId: any) => {
  !onlineUsers.some((user: any) => user.username === username) &&
    onlineUsers.push({ username, socketId });
 
};
```

I wrote this function to avoid duplicate data in the `onlineUsers` array. When I reload the browser, `socketId` is changed but the `username` is the same. So no data is pushed in the `onlineUsers` array.

Now, I write this function instead of the above function

```
const addNewUser = (username: any, socketId: any) => {
  if (onlineUsers.length === 0) {
    onlineUsers.push({ username, socketId });
  }
  if (onlineUsers.length > 0) {
    onlineUsers = onlineUsers.filter((user: any) => user.username !== username);

    onlineUsers.push({ username, socketId });
  }
 
};
```

Now new user data replace the same old user data in the `onlineUsers` array and works fine after reloading.